# PTY allocation request failed on channel 0

Tags: linux, ssh, password, tty, pty

My remote vm server's password has expired,  i cann't change password.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ ssh root@x.x.x.x
root@x.x.x.x's password:
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
WARNING: Your password has expired.
Password change required but no TTY available.
Connection to x.x.x.x closed.
[user@localhost ~]$
```

When I run with -v flag I get more info like this:

```
root@x.x.x.x's password:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to x.x.x.x ([x.x.x.x]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: /bin/bash -i
WARNING: Your password has expired.
Password change required but no TTY available.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 1796, received 2352 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 41062.5, received 53774.5
debug1: Exit status 1
```